# Conjecture on cycle length and primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**That thanks for Peter Košinár's answer,I change the conjecture a lot.**

For positive odd $a$, let $b = A179382((a+1)/2)$,let $b_1 = znorder(Mod(10,a))$,If $b = (a-1)/(2^c)$ and $b_1 = (a-1)/c_1$ for some $c,c_1 > 0$,then $a$ is prime.

Are there grounds to consider this plausible?

Comment: Your question (if you even have one) is quite unclear.  What are you asking here?

Comment: You have zero questions in your post.  On top of this, you have pasted code which seems irrelevant to the post.  Are you asking a question here?  If so, what is it?  If we cannot find your question, how could we help you?

Comment: I have rewritten the question to make it more clear.

Comment: That thanks for Charles's rewrite!

Comment: As the question is now more easily understood, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your understand.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Why do you write your conjecture in the form $(a-1)/b = 2^c$ rather than $\textrm{Od}(a-1) = b$, since you're already using $\textrm{Od}$ in the definition of $b$? 2. You're linking various OEIS sequences with titles which don't show obvious relationships. Can you explain the relationships between these sequences and A179382?

Comment: Given how much you've changed the conjecture, it might be more reasonable to ask "Are there grounds to consider this plausible?" than "How do I prove it?"

Comment: Thanks,I change to  "Are there grounds to consider this plausible?" .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $a=92673 = 3^2 \times 7 \times 1471$. I believe that $b=724$ in this case, which gives us $c=7$. Yet, $a$ is (obviously) not a prime.

Three other counterexamples have been identified subsequently, the largest of them also avoids the $a,b\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$ wriggle:

- $c = 5$ and $a = 143713 = 137\times 1049 = 2^5\times 3^2\times 499 + 1$
- $c = 5$ and $a = 4110529 = 809\times 5081 = 2^6\times 3\times 79\times 271 + 1$
- $c = 6$ and $a = 28688897 = 1009\times 28433 = 2^9\times 137\times 409 + 1$

Comment: The additional condition helps a bit, but isn't sufficient to eliminate all counter-examples; as you can see from the updated answer.

Comment: See OEIS http://oeis.org/A225890

Comment: Could you have a look at this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168045/are-all-counterexamples-of-oeis-a226181-both-poulet-numbers-and-proth-numbers?